# Can we apply stitched border to this pattern?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: I want to add a stitched border to this pattern]

I have applied the stroke but it is appearing at the end but I need it to be 4px below the corners.

```html
<svg viewbox="7.5 0 60 10">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="38%" stop-color="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
      <stop offset="68%" stop-color="rgb(255, 234, 104)" />
    </linearGradient>
 <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
       #pat {
         stroke:black; stroke-width:0.1px; stroke-dasharray:0.3; 
       }
    ]]></style>
  </defs>
  <path id="pat" fill="url(#gradient)" d="M0 6 V5 Q2.5 3.5 5 5 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 V6" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be alternate ways of doing this but in my opinion the easiest way would be to mirror the path in a second `path` element (or using a path def and `use` elements)  and add a small `translate` (in Y axis) transform to it.

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="7.5 0 60 10">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="38%" stop-color="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
      <stop offset="68%" stop-color="rgb(255, 234, 104)" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path d="M0 6 V5 Q2.5 3.5 5 5 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 t5 0 V6" id='wave'/>
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[ #pat {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: .1;
        stroke-dasharray: 0.3;
      }
      ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#wave" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  <use xlink:href="#wave" id="pat" fill="transparent" transform="translate(0,.15)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can avoid the duplicate `d` by moving the path into the `<defs>` area (with no `fill` attribute) and giving it an ID. Then your non-defs code becomes: `<use xlink:href="#pathIDhere" fill="url(#gradient)" /><use xlink:href="#pathIDhere" id="pat" />`

Comment: Ofcourse yes @NiettheDarkAbsol but it becomes more lines of code with two `use` tags, a `def` tag and a `path` inside the `def` tag. I understand where you are coming from though (repetition should be avoided).

Comment: It's less code overall, and it means that if you want to adjust the path at all you only need to do it in one place. I use that technique as much as possible, such as an icon containing two arrows with one reversed is done with a `<defs><path></defs> <use /><use transform />` setup. It firmly establishes "this should be the same" in the markup itself.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I totally agree mate. Maybe my previous comment didn't sound the way I intended it to. The first part (about more lines of code) was in a lighter vein (more like a joke). (*Edit:* I've modified it now :))